# I can't use wifi on just installed lubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager

I've just installed lubuntu, and the only way to use internet is via ethernet.

after: "sudo service network-manager restart", i get "unit network-manager.service not found".

iwconfig gives no wireless extensions.

sudo apt install firmare-iwlwifi network-manager gives:

```
reading package lists...done, building dependency tree... done, reading state information... done, E: Unable to locate package firmare-iwlwifi

Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

If you need something else, just tell me.

**lspci**:

```
nicolo@Nico2pc:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev da)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney HT Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Address Maps
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney DRAM Configuration
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Miscellaneous Configuration
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney PM Configuration
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney NB Performance Monitor
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

**nmcli**

```
nicolo@Nico2pc:~$ nmcli
enxb630426f0fe4: connected to Wired connection 2                                                                                      
        "Xiaomi Mi/Redmi series"                                                                                                      
        ethernet (rndis_host), B6:30:42:6F:0F:E4, hw, mtu 1500                                                                        
        ip4 default                                                                                                                   
        inet4 192.168.215.138/24                                                                                                      
        route4 192.168.215.0/24 metric 100                                                                                            
        route4 default via 192.168.215.144 metric 100
        inet6 fe80::f574:9f40:55ac:28b6/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

enp2s0: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), 4C:ED:FB:2C:F8:55, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.215.144
        interface: enxb630426f0fe4

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.
```

**ip l**

```
nicolo@Nico2pc:~$ ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:ed:fb:2c:f8:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enxb630426f0fe4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:30:42:6f:0f:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**lsb_release -a**

```
nicolo@Nico2pc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

**sudo dmesg| grep iwlwifi**

```
    nicolo@Nico2pc:~$ sudo dmesg| grep iwlwifi
[   29.245330] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   29.301519] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
```

**dkms status**

```
    nicolo@Nico2pc:~$ dkms status
r8168/8.049.02: added
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151156/discussion-on-question-by-nicolo-tiraboschi-i-cant-use-wifi-on-just-installed-l); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I pressed the shut down button for 1minute or more and now it works!